# How do I scale two services in docker-compose (one being a network) and keep them connected to each other's network_mode?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In a scenario where one service connects to the other one's network (as in the example .yml below), is there a way to use --scale to scale both and make them connect to the correct network?

As in app1 uses vpn1 network, app2 uses vpn2 network etc.

```
services:
    vpn:
        image: myvpn

    app:
        image: myapp
        depends_on: vpn
        network_mode: service:vpn
```

I want to be able to run the container with `docker-compose up -d --scale app=5 --scale vpn=5`

The issue is that if I scale both containers the way it's currently setup (lets say with two instances of each service to simplify), both "app" services connect to the first "vpn" service.

I can confirm it by inspecting both `app-1` and `app-2`. In `"HostConfig"` they both show `"NetworkMode": "container:ef37426bec3dbd9c182187d87faf5fe8c92c1e1fa26066f57d163f301af2574e"`, which is the first vpn container.

I understand this is the expected behavior, as the .yml file indicates `network_mode: service:vpn` and not something like `network_mode: service:vpn-${container ID here}`

I want to find a way to set app-1 to use vpn-1 as NetworkMode, app-2 to use vpn-2 as NetworkMode, etc.

Comment: are you actively running into an issue or you're checking in advance? and regardless, please provide more details on the situation

Comment: Hello, I've added more information to the thread. I hope it clarifies it a little bit. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Out of the box `docker-compose` allows for two communication methods:

- VIP - one VIP and DNS record to load balance between the replicas using docker's configuration
- DNSRR - one DNS record and multiple IPs (one for each service) used to allow the user to implement their own load balancer

[image: DNS lookup result]

As far as I managed to research, a configuration as the one you're asking can be achieved using `docker-compose` in one way only, you can set in each client service the backend DNS name by the container name.

For example, if I want to connect to the second instance I'll connect to `docker_backend_2`

[image: container names]

Another way that requires a more hands-on approach would be talking between the services and deciding which will connect to who of the returned IP's to the `nslookup` or some other probing method

If this connectivity configuration is important to you, you should look into [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) where your basic working unit is a [pod](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/multi-container-pods-and-container-communication-in-kubernetes/) and you can spin multiple container images per pod, then you'll spin one of each service inside the pod and connect directly to them internally in the pod's network.